# Suggestion: Link to webapps.stackexchange.com to SuperUser FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

May I suggest that we link to webapps.stackexchange.com on the SuperUser FAQ?  I asked a question there which was closed with the suggestion to ask there instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should also apply to other cases where some application (in the widest sense) questions would be better.

Based on the current betas, this should include:

- Gaming
- Electronic Gadgets
- Statistical Analysis (includes "data visualisation" in its description).

(And should be reviewed as more SE sites come fully on line.)

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ](/faq#dontask) now mentions & Links to WebApps:

> **Power users of web applications**, ask on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)